# Swift Extension with generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I want to extend a generic type like the following:

```
struct A<I> {}
struct B<J> {}
extension A where I: Hashable {} // OK
extension B where J == A<I>, I: Hashable {} // can't compile
```

But I can't. find a way that can compile.
Is this kind of extension possible?

Comment: `A` knows `I`, but `B` does not. You cannot use a generic type in a `where` clause. The argument can be a concrete type, a protocol or an associated type of a protocol, but not an *external* generic.

Comment: You need specify some protocol for `J` from which you will find `I` and will check for `Hashable`

Comment: A third alternative to applying the constraints to the functions inside the extension or making a new protocol, is maybe to try something like `extension B where J == A<any Identifiable>`, this will unfortunately box `I` into a new type automatically, so there's a performance hit, but that might be fine depending on what the extension is doing.